# Why are these images disappearing and how can I fix it (python)?

Tags: python, image, class, url, tkinter

I'm currently working on Tkinter and image stuff in a program. I want to display 9 images on the screen at the same time, but only one image(the last one)will appear on screen at one time. I've isolated the problem in this code so this is the fraction of my code that is causing this problem. The function "download" receives the images from the internet, and then "ext" takes the downloaded images and is supposed to put them on the screen, but not all of them go on.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from threading import *
import random
from io import BytesIO
import urllib
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


    
    
class CardClass:

  def __init__(self):
    self.master = tk.Tk()
    self.master.attributes('-zoomed', True) 
    self.frame = Frame(self.master)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.state = False
    self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", True) 
    self.but = Button(self.master, text="Print Images", command=self.Hand, pad = 150)
    self.but.pack(pady = 12)
    self.cardsList = ["https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg", "https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg", "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg", "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg", "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg", "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg", "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg","https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg"]
  


  def Hand(self):
    self.but.destroy()
    self.newCard = random.sample(self.cardsList, k=9)
    self.slot1 = self.cardsList[0]
    self.slot2 = self.cardsList[1]
    self.slot3 = self.cardsList[2]
    self.slot4 = self.cardsList[3]
    self.slot5 = self.cardsList[4]
    self.slot6 = self.cardsList[5]
    self.slot7 = self.cardsList[6]
    self.slot8 = self.cardsList[7]
    self.slot9 = self.cardsList[8]
    self.ext()
    


    

    

  def download(self, url, ex, ey):
    print("here1")
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
      raw_data = u.read()
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    self.iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    lala = tk.Label(image=self.iimage)
    lala.place(x=ex, y=ey)
    return self.iimage

  def ext(self):
  
    self.download(self.newCard[0], 50, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[1], 100, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[2], 150, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[3], 200, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[4], 150, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[5], 300, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[6], 350, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[7], 400, 150)
    self.download(self.newCard[8], 450, 150)
    



     
  


    
    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = CardClass()
    w.master.mainloop()
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: It is because you have used same instance variable `self.iimage` for the nine images, so only the reference of last image is saved.  Better use attribute of the label created instead of instance variable, i.e. add `lala.image = self.iimage`.

Comment: @acw1668. `tk.Label (image=...` already does that. The problem is that the label has no parent and therefore gets destroyed the moment the function exits.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please note that `lala.image` is not the same as `tk.Label(image=...)`.  `lala.image` is an attribute and `tk.Label(image=...)` is an option.  Also every widget has a parent, if not specified, it will be the root window.

Comment: @acw1668. Are you saying that `image` is not a property that redirects to the option?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, `lala.image` will not update the image of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I understand why this should be, but the problem is, in fact, that the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instances evaporate when the function ends.  **That shouldn't be the case.**  The `Label` widget should be holding a reference that keeps it alive, but if you store those PhotoImage objects in a list, as below, the code works:

```
  def Hand(self):
    self.but.destroy()
    self.newCard = random.sample(self.cardsList, k=9)
    self.keep = []
    self.ext()

  def download(self, url, ex, ey):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
      raw_data = u.read()
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data)).resize((50,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    Label(self.master, image=iimage).place(x=ex,y=ey)
    self.keep.append(iimage)
```